# MVC: How to make DropdownList field (with Chosen Plugin) Required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, validation, jquery-chosen

I have declared a parameter in my model  as

```
[Required]
public int? param{get; set;}
```

and defined this on a dropdown list. Everything works fine and the data validation works, until I add the plugin, [Chosen](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen). When I add the plugin, there is no validation proior to submission. How can i keep the data validation when the plugin is applied on the Select element?

Comment: do you mean js-unobtrusive validation? are there any errors in JS-console?

Comment: There are no errors. There is simply no validation as the form can be submitted without any selection made on the dropdown. I just want it validate as MVC does it. Yes,   js-unobtrusive validation

Comment: does it validate other fields? is unobtrusive-validation.js is included in the page?

Comment: Yes, any other field without the plugin works fine. When I remove plugin from the dropdownlist, validation works. Just does not work when I add the plugin.

Comment: oh-uh.. just checked our system. We have the same problem - unobtrusive validation does not work on fields with chozen. But we still get server-side validation.

Comment: How do you prevent submission without a selection made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/473#issuecomment-4054176), I went to the chose js file and changed the this.form_field_jq.hide() to 'this.form_field_jq.css("position","absolute").css("left","-9999px")'

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this :) !